# Is there a name for these kinds of graphs?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, dataset, cumulative-distribution-function

I am just wondering - is there a name for these kinds of graphs? The associated text that comes with the graph says the following:

[image]

> Figure 2 presents a view of the distribution of correctable errors
>   over DIMMs. It plots the fraction of errors made up by the top x
>   percent of DIMMs with errors. For all platforms, the top 20% of DIMMs
>   with errors make up over 94% of all observed errors. For Platform C
>   and D, the distribution is even more skewed, with the top 20% of DIMMs
>   comprising more than 99.6% of all errors. Note that the graph in
>   Figure 2 is plotted on a log-log scale and that the lines for all
>   platforms appear almost straight indicating a power-law distribution.

I don't understand how this figure was plotted nor the description that comes with it because none of the values are visible on a log-log scale. It does not look like a conventional CDF curve to me. I have some data as follows:

```
Platform | Device | #Failures
Type 1   | A      | 1123
Type 1   | B      | 362
Type 1   | C      | 123
Type 1   | D      | 21
```

Now to get a CDF, I would take the `#Failures` column and plot its CDF in which I will get a graph with:

- X-Axis: #Failures
- Y-Axis: Cumulative Distribution of devices

So I figured I will normalize the `#Failures` column, draw the CDF of the normalized values Then I will get a graph with:

- X-Axis: % of Failures
- Y-Axis: Cumulative Distribution of devices

And then flip it? But I still don't understand what this new graph is telling me that the conventional CDF is not showing. Can someone shed some light onto this?

Comment: This looks like an empirical CDF of the fraction of dimms with correctable errors with both the x and y axes in log-scale.